# PostgreSQL Cursor Error

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I have the code:

```
 DECLARE 
      cliente_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM cliente;
      cliente cliente.id_clie%TYPE;
      nom cliente.nom_clie%TYPE;  
    BEGIN
      OPEN cliente_cursor;
      FETCH cliente_cursor INTO cliente, nom;
```

But I cannot run it. The following error appears:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "cliente"
LINE 3: cliente cliente.id_clie% TYPE;
        ^
```

I have the table "cliente" which has:

[image: Table cliente]

I want to create a cursor that shows only the content of the columns: id_clie, nom_clie of the previous table.

I have also used:

```
create or replace function facturas_cliente()
  returns table (a int, b character varying(40))
  language plpgsql as $$
declare 
  x cliente%rowtype ;
  cliente_cursor cursor for select id_clie, nom_clie from cliente 
  order by id_clie;
begin
  for x in cliente_cursor loop
    return next x;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR: RETURN NEXT can not have parameters in a function with OUT parameters
LINE 9: return next x;
                    ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First issue is strange. I tested on PostgreSQL 9.5 (but same code should to work on 9.2 and newer):

```
CREATE TABLE cliente(id_clie int, tel_clie varchar(15), dir_clie varchar(15));

DO $$
DECLARE
  cliente_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM cliente;
  cliente cliente.id_clie%TYPE;
  tel cliente.tel_clie%TYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cliente_cursor;
END;
$$;
```

And it works without any issue. It looks like some mistyped error.

Second issue is clear. When function has a `OUT` variables or is declared as `TABLE` function, then `RETURN NEXT` has to be without expression. Returned composite value is based on actual context of `OUT` variables (columns declared in `TABLE` clause are `OUT` variables too). Your code should to be:

```
create or replace function facturas_cliente() 
returns table (a int, b character varying(40))
language plpgsql as $$
declare 
  cliente_cursor cursor for select id_clie, nom_clie 
                            from cliente 
                            order by id_clie;
  r record;
begin
  for r in cliente_cursor -- a,b ~ OUT var declared in TABLE() clause
  loop
    a := r.id_clie; b := r.nom_clie; 
    return next;  -- not: return next x;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

This code can be reduced in PL/pgSQL two ways:

1. use a SQL function

   ```
   create or replace function facturas_cliente() 
   returns table (a int, b character varying(40))
   language sql as $$
     select id_clie, nom_clie from cliente order by id_clie;
   $$ language plpgsql;
   ```
2. use a `RETURN QUERY` statement in plpgsql:

   ```
   create or replace function facturas_cliente() 
   returns table (a int, b character varying(40))
   language sql as $$
   BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY SELECT id_clie, nom_clie 
                   FROM cliente 
                   ORDER BY id_clie;
      RETURN;
   END;
   $$ language plpgsql;
   ```

Attention: these function can block a SQL optimizer if you use it in some complex query than trivial. Personally I don't like it. Use a view instead. It works like you need and there is no risk with optimization.

```
CREATE VIEW facturas_cliente
   AS SELECT id_clie, nom_clie 
      FROM cliente 
      ORDER BY id_clie;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the second clode of block but it shows an error regarding to the for loop. ERROR: a FOR loop of a cursor must have only one target variable

Comment: hmm - a artific limit for compatibility with PL/SQL :/. I forgot it. Fixed